# Why does Python print a set of numbers as ordered

Tags: python

I tried print this in the python idle {6,3,7}. The output was {3,6,7}. Shouldn't sets be unordered and print a different order each time? Is it something related to the way hash maps are built?

Comment: Just because you cannot _rely_ on any particular order does not mean that python _must_ print them in a different order each time. With `{6,3,8}` it is reporting `set([8, 3, 6])` for me, so it is certainly not generally the case that they are coming back in order. Regarding the "each time", I suspect that if you iterate over the same set repeatedly without modifying it, then the order will be deterministically the same, even if it is not any particular order, although someone else will have to confirm that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why python set displays in "same" order if sets are unordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701618/why-python-set-displays-in-same-order-if-sets-are-unordered)

Answer (score 1):

Sets are indeed unordered in Python.  The fact that your particular example set happens to give elements in apparently sorted order when iterated over (and appears reproducible in python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3) does not negate this fact, and another example gives elements in an order which is neither the order in which they were added to the set, nor is it sorted.

```
>>> list(set([6,3,7]))
[3, 6, 7]

>>> list(set([6,3,8]))
[8, 3, 6]
```

For the values 6, 3 and 8, the order in which iteration over a python set containing those values will yield elements does at least appear to be consistent, regardless of the order in which the set was populated.  However, this says nothing about whether this result is generally true, and in any case it should be considered an implementation detail.  User code should not assume any ordering at all.

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
>>> for p in multiset_permutations([3,6,8]): print(p, list(set(p)))
... 
([3, 6, 8], [8, 3, 6])
([3, 8, 6], [8, 3, 6])
([6, 3, 8], [8, 3, 6])
([6, 8, 3], [8, 3, 6])
([8, 3, 6], [8, 3, 6])
([8, 6, 3], [8, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

See, I understand your concern, and I was confused in the beginning as well, when I first saw it. But I am certain you know sets are unordered and unindexed. Hence it cannot be the case that the elements of any set are ordered. Try running something like `a = {6,2,90,4,12,0,4000,345}` or your example -- on Jupyter Notebook, or on IDLE or through command prompt. It's arranged differently.

On Jupyter, it gave: 
`{0, 2, 4, 6, 12, 90, 345, 4000}`

On Command Prompt:
`{0, 4000, 2, 4, 6, 12, 345, 90}`

And when you print the elements of a set one by one, it will be shown in the order:

```
4000
2
4
6
12
345
90
```

I believe you were trying on Jupyter. They always seem to sort it when you want to see a variable like `a`, here.

And for your doubt, hash map concept applies to dictionaries, and not to sets.

Comment: Thank you. But I did them on idle. Also I read on geeksforgeeks that sets use hash maps in the underlying code? Do you know what data strucuture it uses?

Comment: @MilanMuhammed the data structures (hash maps) are an implementation detail that you can't count on being unchanging.  The implementation of dictionaries changed in 3.6 so that they preserve the insertion order, but sets are still unordered.