# Why is Python's set() sorting a list in some cases?

Tags: python, list, random, set

I'm confused by the behavior of Python's `set()` in this example:

```py
random_number_list = [randint(1, 10) for _ in range(10)]
# This will be sorted!
unique_numbers = set(random_number_list)

print(
    f"random_number_list/unique_numbers with same upper bound for randint() and range():\n{random_number_list=}\n{unique_numbers=}\n"
)

random_number_list = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(10)]
# This will not be sorted.
unique_numbers = set(random_number_list)

print(
    f"random_number_list/unique_numbers with different upper bound for randint() and range():\n{random_number_list=}\n{unique_numbers=}\n"
)
```

It seems like `set()` is sorting the `random_number_list` if the length of the list and the upper bound of `randint()` are the same:

```
➜  ch-2 python --version
Python 3.10.0
➜  ch-2 python find_k_smallest.py 
random_number_list/unique_numbers with same upper bound for randint() and range():
random_number_list=[10, 1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 8]
unique_numbers={1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10}

random_number_list/unique_numbers with different upper bound for randint() and range():
random_number_list=[35, 1, 17, 26, 17, 74, 26, 11, 44, 13]
unique_numbers={1, 35, 74, 11, 44, 13, 17, 26}
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) state:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

What's going on here? Why is `set()` sorting the `random_number_list` in certain cases and not others?

***Edit*** Neither of these questions addresses my issue:

- [my Python multiprocesses are apparently not independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845073/my-python-multiprocesses-are-apparently-not-independent/64866191#64866191)
- [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, I just don't understand why it's happening and was hoping someone could enlighten me.

Comment: If it happens "in certain cases and not others", then the docs are telling you the truth and you shouldn't count on ordering even though it may occur.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61100205/12416453

Comment: Sets are generally unordered(doesn't mean it's strictly unsorted). The ordering may change from implementation to implementation.

Comment: Interesting. I only have a few Python binaries installed and all of them exhibit the same behavior, but I can see that there are differences from the link @Ch3steR posted. I guess I'll chalk this up to an oddity of the implementation! I didn't know if this was something Pythonistas know about but newcomers don't, as I'm still pretty new to the language.

Comment: The bottom-line is to not write code that counts on the ordering of members of a set being in any particular order — so it will work regardless of the implementation.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845073/my-python-multiprocesses-are-apparently-not-independent/64866191#64866191

Comment: @PeterO. neither of those answer my question. I'm curious as to why `set()` is ordering its members sometimes when the size of the `list` is related to the bounds of `randint()`. I don't care about an ordered `set` implementation, though. Thanks for the links, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually answer your question.  Many implementations of sets use an implementation similar to hashtables.  Items are hashed and placed into an "array" based on that hash value.

Notice that for small integers, hash(x) == x.  So 1 will go into slot 1, 2 will go into slot 2, 3 into slot 3, etc.  Then when the elements are read, you'll literally get the elements sorted.

However if your integers are bigger than the array size, then their placement in the array will be modulo the size of the array.  They will no longer be sorted.

Again, I have not actually looked at the Python implementation.  This is simply a possible explanation of what could be happening.

Comment: There isn't a single "Python implementation", there are several, so looking at any one of them won't tell you anything that can be generalized.

Comment: This is very enlightening, thank you! It lines up with what I'm seeing as well.

Comment: @martineau.  I agree that there is no single "Python implementation", but I think we can agree that CPython is the most commonly used implementation.  Artifacts of CPython's implementation (e.g. ordered dictionaries) sometimes become part of the standard.   And yes, the implementation of sets in CPython appears to be pretty much what I expected.  And no, OP shouldn't rely on the set being sorted.

Answer (score 2):

"Unordered" does not mean "not sorted". It means no attempt is made to provide any particular order; the order that falls out from the implementation may or may not be a sorted order.

Comment: Right. But it *is* ordered every time when the size of the `list` that I convert to a `set` is related to the upper bound of the `randint()` that populates the `list`. That's the part that is confusing to me. There must be something ordering the `set` for this condition, I just wasn't sure if that was a known property or something that seems to be a weird implementation quirk.

Comment: It's an implication quirk, the particular quirk being that sets are based on hash tables, the hash value is the integer itself, and that you aren't using any integers larger than the size of the hash table. At least on my machine, it took about 2 seconds to find a set that *isn't* sorted: `set([1000000000000000000, 2])`.

Comment: Correct, not all sets are sorted. I also demonstrated that in my example. But, certain sets are *always* sorted. The hash table explanation makes sense, I'm researching it now. I don't have a CS background but I'm currently studying CS topics so this has been very enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in a comment:

> I'm curious as to why `set()` is ordering its members sometimes when the size of the `list` is related to the bounds of `randint()`.

That is an implementation detail that an application should not concern itself with, as even in Python 3.7 (and 3.10), `set`s are [documented as "unordered collection[s]"](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). You can look up, for example, the [source code of CPython](https://github.com/Python/cpython) to find out [how `set`s are implemented in CPython](https://github.com/Python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c).

See also:

- [Why does Python print a set of numbers as ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360830)

Comment: I understand that it's not something to rely on, I was merely curious why it was happening. Thanks for the links, this seems to be something I can dig into: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c.